# boundary condition is inconsistent with the solution in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

```
dsd[q_?NumericQ] := NDSolve[{D[f1[t, x], t] == q D[x D[f1[t, x], x], x], 
  f1[0, x] == f1[1, x] == UnitStep[x - 1], f1[t, 1] == 1, 
  (D[f1[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 0}, f1, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]
solt[t_, x_] = f1[t, x] /. dsd[0.011][[1]]
```

The solution obtained does not match with the boundary condition given in t at t=0 and 1. Please help me out to solve the problem

Comment: What is the PDE you want to solve? t makes me think it might be a time dependent problem. Also the use of Inactive might be neccessary. If you could edit your question such that it contains the equation you would like to solve, that would help.

Answer (score 2):

Running the code (with Mathematica 10.0.2.0 in Windows 8.1) yields a warning message instead.

```
NDSolve::femcscd: The PDE is convection dominated and the result may not be stable. Adding artificial diffusion may help. >>
```

but nonetheless produces an answer,

[image]

Its appearance confirms the warning message.  The computation is unstable.  (I suspect that you would obtain the same result upon rerunning the calculation with a fresh notebook after restarting Mathematica.)

Incidentally, I reformatted your code to make it more accessible to readers.  (It produced the same results before and after the reformatting.)

**Comments on Boundary Conditions**

The boundary condition `f1[0, x] == f1[1, x] == UnitStep[x - 1]` is equivalent to `f1[0, x] == f1[1, x] == 0` over the computational range `{x, 0, 1}`.  Also, since the equation to be solved is the diffusion equation, specifying boundary conditions at both `t == 0` and `t == 1` may be inappropriate.  If `f1[0, x] == 0` only is used instead, the warning message given in the Question appears.  This is because two of the boundary conditions now are `f1[0, x] == 0, f1[t, 1] == 1`, which is inconsistent at `x == t == 0`.  (Why `NDSolve` did not give this warning with `f1[1, x] == 0` also specified is unclear.)  The boundary conditions easily can be made consistent without changing the character of the problem, for instance by using `f1[0, x] == 0, f1[t, 1] == 1 - Exp[-100 t]`, whereupon the warning error disappears.  With these changes, the code reads,

```
dsd[q_?NumericQ] := NDSolve[{D[f1[t, x], t] == q D[x D[f1[t, x], x], x], f1[0, x] == 0, 
  f1[t, 1] == 1 - Exp[-100 t], (D[f1[t, x], x] /. x -> 0) == 0}, f1, {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}];
solt[t_, x_] = f1[t, x] /. dsd[0.011][[1]]
```

and a plot of the solution, produced as before by

```
Plot3D[solt[t, x], {t, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, AxesLabel -> {t, x}, PlotRange -> All]
```

is the reasonable

[image]